# What is a list of 2 or 3 english words which somtimes make good substitutes for the word "quam"?

Tags: comparative

If you were to fill in the blank cell of the following table with an English word, what would you write?

| ego | beatior | sum | **quam** | ille |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| I | happier | I am |  | he |

Comment: The downvote isn't mine, but: this question is easily answered with a dictionary. If you looked it up and are still puzzled, you should explain what research you've done and why you're not satisfied with what you found.

Answer (score 3):

The usual English way to express that would be "I am happier **than** him".

Comment: Latin does use the nominative here (as does old-fashioned / highly formal English).

Comment: Am I misremembering? I thought comparatives always took the ablative in this construction.

Comment: I am in fact misremembering.

Comment: There are two options, ablative of comparison without *quam*, or *quam* with the same case as the other comparandum.

Comment: Sticklers might bristle at "him."